# Include a .pro file in Qt?

Tags: qt, unit-testing

I have a project which has lots of includepaths, source and header files. The project is run as a standalone application (it's not a library).

I would like to implement tests (Qt unit test framework) for new features for that application and for that, I require the includes, sources and header files of the (application) project to be available in the (testing) project.

I have tried putting the following in the testing project .pro file:

```
include(../application/app.pro)     #app.pro is the application project
```

However first it complains about `main.cpp`, and if I comment that out there is a parsing error. (commenting main.cpp is bad since I'm changing the main project just so that the testing will compile)

I can get the behavior I want by manually copying all the includepath's, source and header fields from the (application) project but am looking for a cleaner way.

What would be the optimal way to do this? Is it possible to painlessly include one .pro into another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform two modifications:

1. Separate out all header files and build-specific settings into a *.pri file. This is what you need instead of including a *.pro.
2. Move all business logic into a library in order to be able to test it in a separate project.

E.g., you will have build.pri:

```
# build.pri
TOPDIR = $$PWD
INCLUDEPATH += . \
               $$TOPDIR/include

DEPENDPATH += $$TOPDIR

INCLUDEPATH += $$TOPDIR/additional/libararies

HEADERS += all.h \
           your.h \
           headers.h \
           of.h \
           interest.h

QT      += xml
# etc., etc.
```

and core.pro

```
# core.pro
TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG  += dll thread create_prl
QT      += network xml xmlpatterns sql

include(../build.pri)

HEADERS  += \
            headers.h

SOURCES  += sources.cpp \
            many_of_them.cpp

TARGET     = core
# etc., etc.
```

(note the `include(../build.pri)`), and then make your main project `app.pro` as a `subdirs` project with `core` and `gui` as components of application, and `test.pro` with obligative `core` and as many tests as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. You have excluded the source files from .pri. From what i understand, the `test.pro` would require `core` to be pre built before to run the tests. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, a .pri is generally not a good place for sources (though not always, of course). The idea is to separate all general configuration in a .pri in order to be able to make several simple projects of .pro-s based on them, e.g. app.pro (`subdirs` of `core` and `gui`, both include build.pri) and tests.pro (`subdirs` of `core` and `test1`, `test2`, etc.). Note that `core` goes first, that causes it to be built first.

Comment: A good though incomplete manual to qmake projects is http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html. And there is a source of knowledge that is not so obvious, the so called Undocumented qmake, http://qtcenter.org/wiki/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake. Hope, these will save your time in the future.

Comment: So, for each target, I have to create a new .pro file? Why Qt don't explicitly describe this on the qmake tutorial?