# Unit test large Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I have a fairly large Qt GUI project, which unfortunately lacks proper unit tests.

I'm planning to have a test project with a test source file for every class.

I digged through a lot of Qt's official docs, however there are some questions left:

- How can I create a test suite? It seems all docs and tutorials cover only writing one test, but how do I bundle my unit tests efficiently?
- How can I integrate the test execution into Qt 
  Creator? Maybe running the tests as post-build step would be interesting?
- Should I add all normal source files to the test project or is there a way to create a static lib?

Any pointers to tutorials covering hint testing of a larger Qt project are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not have a lot of time to do perfect unit testing in Qt. I did, however, figure out how to get the main plumbing working. I hope that this can help you, although you could probably do a better job than I did by studying the [Writing Unit Tests guide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Writing_Unit_Tests).

> How can I create a test suite? It seems all docs and tutorials cover only writing one test, but how do I bundle my unit tests efficiently?

You can organize "suites" by collecting unit tests (which are slots on objects) into objects and composing those objects.

**test_example.pro**

```
TARGET = test_example
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += testcase
QT += testlib core

... INCLUDEPATH, SOURCES, HEADERS, etc...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include "MainTest.h"

// This macro introduces an event loop
QTEST_MAIN(MainTest)
```

**MainTest.h**

```
class MainTest : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

private slots:

  // Each slot is a unit test
  void init()
  {
  }

  // Create a "test suite" by bundling tests into objects
  void runFirstSuite()
  {
    FirstSuiteUiTest first;
    first.test();  // runs 10 tests

    FirstSuiteIoTest second;
    second.test();  // runs 999 tests

    ...
  }

  void SecondSuite() 
  {
    QFAIL("This suite is not really a suite, and it always fails");
  }
};
```

You can also organize tests into physical file structures. I used a subdirs project as my root .pro file so I could build artifacts (dynamic and static archives, binaries) and run many collections of unit tests.

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += src/core
SUBDIRS += src/some_dll
SUBDIRS += src/test/awesome_core_test_1 #Holds many suites
SUBDIRS += src/test/awesome_core_test_2 #Holds many other suites!

core.depends = core
awesome_core_test_1.depends = core
awesome_core_test_2.depends = core
```

So by organizing unit tests into object compositions and physical files, you can some granularity of organization. There may be better or different ways, but I am not sure.

> How can I integrate the test execution into Qt Creator? Maybe running the tests as post-build step would be interesting?

Add `CONFIG += testcase` into your .pro file. This creates a build target. Invoke the build and tests by running `make check`

> Should I add all normal source files to the test project or is there a way to create a static lib?

You can do either, just like in any other project.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a test suite? It seems all docs and tutorials cover only writing one test, but how do I bundle my unit tests efficiently?

In "Qt unit test class" each private slot is a unit test. Not exists other standard ways for adding new tests, but exist non documentary qmake feature. You can read about [in this forum thread](http://forum.qt.io/topic/13817/running-many-qtest-tests-automatically-or-not/5)

> How can I integrate the test execution into Qt Creator? Maybe running the tests as post-build step would be interesting?

You can add CONFIG+=testcase test project and this will generate additional make target - check. Of course, you can add this build step anywhere. Also, you can read about here - [Writing_Unit_Tests](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Writing_Unit_Tests)

> Should I add all normal source files to the test project or is there a way to create a static lib?

You can create static or dynamic lib with sources and link them to test project, or you can add sources to test project like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153895/how-to-write-the-qmake-file-for-a-test-case)

By the way, you can watch example of unit testing with Qt [here](https://bitbucket.org/milovidov/qtyandexapi/src)

Comment: This is the right answer. I would only add the possibility of including the library files to the test project (for example, doing `SOURCES += ../lib/*cpp`) as an alternative to testing the library API.

Comment: `In Qt unit test class the each private slots is a unit test` - say what?

Comment: You don't say "the each" - just "each" or "each of the". I know it is not an "English language" site but still, English is primary here and yours needs polishing. I suspect you do literal translation from your native language, but that is just not proper English. I am still not entirely sure what most of the sentences in that answer say, I will have to "guess".

Comment: @ddriver yes, my english level not enough for you, but I'm trying. Thank you for attention to my post.